# OneToMany spring form issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, one-to-many

While trying to create spring form for a OneToMany Mapping, i am getting following error

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'reminder[0].id' of bean class [com.medicine.yourmedics.model.Medication_$$_jvst99a_7]: Field 'reminder[0].id' does not exist

My Pojo class for Medication is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEDICATION")
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Medication {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "medication")
private List<Reminder> reminder = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
```

Reminder Pojo looks like

```
public class Reminder {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "medication_id")
private Medication medication;
```

I have create a form for medication in which i am trying to access reminder id

```
<c:forEach items="${medication.reminder}" varStatus="loop">
    <form:input path="reminder[${loop.index}].id" />
</c:forEach>
```

Please help me guys. I am having hard time finding out the issue in this.

Comment: Do you have getters and setters in beans?

Comment: yes i do have getters and setters in both the beans

Comment: Why don't you have `private int id;` in Medication?

Comment: thats a typo. In actual code its there

Comment: Show controller GET method and full form in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch()) for @OneToMany...

> (Optional) Whether the association
>   should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy
>   is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the
>   associated entities must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a
>   hint to the persistence provider runtime.
>
> **Default:
>   javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY**

Try `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "medication", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` to ask hibernate to eagerly load the data in the list instead of providing a proxy

Comment: tried it. But still the same issue. Is anything else i can try